# combine both background image, background drawable style on a button

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

Im wondering if its possible to combine both having an image on a button and using a drawable source and having text above that?

I'm currently using this as my button style in drawable/red_btn.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#ef4444" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#992f2f" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#ef4444"
                android:endColor="#992f2f"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#992f2f" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

And then my button

```
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/testButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Income"
                android:textSize="15dip"
                android:background="@drawable/red_btn"
    android:textColor="#fff"
     android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Which looks like this

[image]

Now I would like to add another .png image (arrow.png) above this button to the right like this

[image]

Is this possible, and if, how can I do it?

Thanks in advance.
**__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________**

**Edit**

After following **Luksprog's** advice below I now have **"red_btn_normal.xml"** in drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#ef4444" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#992f2f" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#ef4444"
                android:endColor="#992f2f"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#992f2f" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

and **red_btn_pressed.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#ef4444" />

            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#992f2f" />

            <corners android:radius="3dp" />

            <padding
                android:bottom="10dp"
                android:left="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:top="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow" />
    </item>


</layer-list>
```

And then i create my button like this "red_btn.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/red_btn_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/red_btn_normal"></item>

</selector>
```

And finally my button

```
    <Button
                android:id="@+id/testButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Income"
                android:textSize="15dip"
                android:background="@drawable/red_btn"

    android:textColor="#fff"
     android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Problem is that it only shows the white arrows when I **click** the button and it dosn't show it when its **not pressed**. What is wrong with the code? =)

Comment: Button has a TextView and you could setCompoundDrawables for the textview. So you could just setDrawableLeft/Right/Bottom/Top to the textview.

Answer (score 12):

> Im wondering if its possible to combine both having an image on a
>   button and using a drawable source and having text above that?

Yes, it's possible. Your selector will become:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/red_btn_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/red_btn_normal"></item>

</selector>
```

where the two drawables are two `layer-list` drawables with the first item being the items from your initial selector and the second being the `.png` image wrapped as a bitmap drawbale. For example for `red_btn_pressed.xml` you'll have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#ef4444" />

            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#992f2f" />

            <corners android:radius="3dp" />

            <padding
                android:bottom="10dp"
                android:left="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:top="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow" />
    </item>


</layer-list>
```

and the `red_btn_normal.xml` will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:endColor="#992f2f"
                android:startColor="#ef4444" />

            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#992f2f" />

            <corners android:radius="3dp" />

            <padding
                android:bottom="10dp"
                android:left="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:top="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/allowed" android:gravity="right"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Keep in mind that the arrow image will be on the right of the text **only** if the size of the `Button` allows it(as its part of the `Button`'s background). If you're trying to impose some sort of positioning relation between the text of the `Button` and that arrow image then you'll need to extend the `Button` class and do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the help sofar. Didn't quite work though, the arrow only shows when I press the button, despite having the code exactly as you have it above, I must be doing something wrong? =)

Comment: @anders Maybe my answer wasn't that clear, the idea was to place the bitmap drawable in both `layer-list`. Check my edited answer.

Answer (score 3):

I went with the simple

```
<Button
                android:id="@+id/testButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Income"
                android:textSize="15dip"
                android:background="@drawable/red_btn"
android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow"
    android:textColor="#fff"
     android:textStyle="bold" />
```